# heroku pg:push could not write to output file: Invalid argument

Tags: heroku, pg-dump

I am trying to push my local database to heroku, but it looks like it fails along the way. Any idea what I could be doing wrong? Here is the stack trace:

```
>> heroku pg:push my_db_name my_app_name::BROWN
Password:
pg_dump: reading schemas
pg_dump: reading user-defined tables
pg_dump: reading extensions
...
pg_dump: saving encoding = UTF8
pg_dump: saving standard_conforming_strings = on
pg_dump: saving database definition
pg_dump: [custom archiver] WARNING: ftell mismatch with expected position -- ftell used
pg_dump: dumping contents of table XXX
pg_dumpp: [gc_ursetsotmo raer:c h[iavrecrh]i ver] WARNdINGi:d  fntoetl lf imnids mmaatgcihc  wsittrhi negx pienc tfeidl ep ohseiatdieorn
-- ftell used
pg_dump: dumping contents of table XXX
pg_dump: [custom archiver] WARNING: ftell mismatch with expected position -- ftell used
pg_dump: dumping contents of table ZZZ
pg_dump: [custom archiver] could not write to output file: Invalid argument
Password:
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a known problem on Windows 7. Unfortunately there is no solution. But there is a work around:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export

Answer (score -1):

My guess would be that you are out of free disk space to store your backupset.

Comment: it would be better if you could explain why your suggestion is going to be helpful

Comment: Obviously if that's the reason anyone having the same problem could use different disk with higher capacity as a place for the backup and hence solve the problem.